# SQL query : Not getting correct output

Tags: sql

I have below table instead of zero in add_days and remove_days I want respected output 
CAN anyone help me to get the correct SQL statement

I TRIED A LOT

```
E_ID H_ID   ADD_DAYS  REMOVE_DAYS
1   1   "2" "0"
2   2   "4" "0"
2   2   "0" "1"
3   3   "2" "0"
3   3   "0" "4"
3   4   "0" "4"
```

ACTUAL

```
E_ID H_ID   ADD_DAYS  REMOVE_DAYS
1   1   "2" "0"
2   2   "4" "0"
2   2   "0" "1"
3   3   "2" "0"
3   3   "0" "4"
3   4   "0" "4"
```

EXPECTED

```
E_ID H_ID   ADD_DAYS  REMOVE_DAYS
1   1   "2" "0"
2   2   "4" "1"
3   3   "2" "4"
3   4   "0" "4"
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? And which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select e_id, h_id, max(ADD_DAYS),max(REMOVE_DAYS)
from tablename
group by e_id, h_id
```